# `PlotRangePadding -> 0` still leaves 1 pixel border

Tags: image, rasterize, padding

The following should create a 50x50 image named `/tmp/nopad.gif` with mostly random colors and a red border:

```
 
t1024 = Table[If[i==1 || i==50 || j==1 || j==50, {1,0,0}, RandomReal[1,3]],  
 {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}]; 
t1025 = Graphics[Raster[t1024], PlotRangePadding -> 0]; 
Export["/tmp/nopad.gif", t1025, ImageSize -> {50,50}]
```

Here's the image: [image]

It's hard to tell directly, but if you load the image into ImageMagick's display and use the magnify feature, you'll see a one pixel white border at the right and bottom edges:

[image]

Note that display counts starting at 0, so the highlighted white pixel is the 50th pixel in both the x and y directions.

As nearly as I can tell, setting `ImageSize -> {51,51}` and then trimming the result is a workaround, but is there a better way to get rid of this border?

As a note, I realize I could've just loaded the image back into Mathematica to confirm it has a border, but, hopefully, the above is convincing enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ImagePadding -> None`:

```
t1024 = Table[
   If[i == 1 || i == 50 || j == 1 || j == 50, {1, 0, 0}, 
    RandomReal[1, 3]], {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}];
t1025 = Graphics[Raster[t1024], PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> None];
Export["/tmp/nopad.gif", t1025, ImageSize -> {50, 50}]

CellPrint@
 ExpressionCell[Import["/tmp/nopad.gif"], Background -> Black, Magnification -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!